# How to handle onclick event in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new in javascript and I'm trying to hide or show a submenu with the onclick event.
Here's the code:
javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        bool shown = false;
        document.getElementById("test").onclick = SubMenuDisplay();

        function SubMenuDisplay()
        {
            alert("Hello World!");
            if(!show)
            {
                $('subm').show();
                shown = true;
            }
            else
            {
                $('subm').hide();
                shown = false;
            }
        }
</script>
```

and html:

```
 <li id="test"><a href="#">Account</a>
     <ul id="subm">
         <li><a href="./account.php#login">Login</a></li>
         <li><a href="./account.php#signup">Sign up</a></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
```

but my onclick event doesn't work at all.

Is someone can help?

Comment: Have you tried to read a little bit more about Javascript before asking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I believe you are trying to pull off:

```
<a href="#" id="test" onclick="SubMenuDisplay();">Account</a>

<ul id="subm">
    <li><a href="./account.php#login">Login</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="./account.php#signup">Sign up</a>

    </li>
</ul>

var shown = false;
$("#subm").hide();

function SubMenuDisplay() {
    alert("Hello World!");
    if (!shown) {
        $('#subm').show();
        shown = true;
    } else {
        $('#subm').hide();
        shown = false;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/wyrogc77/

JavaScript is dynamically typed, so you do not need to declare types, as you did with `bool shown = false;`. This can be replaced with `var shown = false;`. JavaScript will figure out that this is a boolean.

Beyond that your code just needed a little massaging. You were assigning the `id="test"` to the `li` element, when you should just assign it to the `a`, and style the `a` like an `li`, with something like:

```
#test {
    list-style-type: bullet;
    list-style-position: inside;
    display: list-item;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, I can now get the alert, but I still can't hide or show the submenu. 
I'm used to make if(!boolean){} in c#, so I did same in javascript, but is it possible that it makes problems?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? In my fiddle you can see that the menu is hidden, and then shown when clicking `Account`. Did you try this? http://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/wyrogc77/

Comment: I didn't try your link sorry ^^'
on jsfiddle is works, I did same in my project but id doesn't work.
I check again my code

Comment: That means your project has conflicting code. You will need to provide everything relevant for us to help you.

Comment: You did have a typo here also: `if (!show)` instead of `if (!shown)`.

Comment: I don't think there's conflicting code, I can past all the code if you want but I think it will be useless
But my browser says I have an error here:
$("#subm").hide();
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Are you loading in the jQuery library?

Comment: Now I do ^^'
I think I should read more about javascript/jquery before continuing my webSites ....
But still an error (I hope this is the last) : <li id="test"><a href="#" onclick="SubMenuDisplay()">Account</a>  
Uncaught ReferenceError: SubMenuDisplay is not defined

Comment: Look at my example where I moved `id="test"` into the `<a>`.

Comment: Also, you need to load in your JavaScript through the html, with something like: `<script src="script.js"></script>`.

Comment: I erased my function et retyped it, now it works.
I replaced the jquery elements with javascript, is it possible that all my problems came from the jquery elements?

Comment: and what does it change if I add my script with 
<script src="myscript.js"></script>    
or that I make the script into my html file?

Comment: You have to include your JavaScript file in your HTML. Why don't you provide an example or fiddle of the complete code you are working on?

Comment: I just started the website yesterday and I make a c# wpf app' that will comunicate with the site (it's just for a personnal test)

Comment: and what I did is that I wrote the js into my header tag and the header is included on other page with php

Comment: Using an external file is better practice.

Comment: but the final result is same ...

Comment: But I think I will make a separate file for js.

Comment: You have not yet provided the non-working code. As shown in my example the code can work, with some adjustments. You should edit your original question to show the issue you are having or if your issue is resolved, accept an answer or delete your question.

Comment: sorry, I accepted a question earlier but seems I failed ... and thanks for your help. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `()`:

```
document.getElementById("test").onclick = SubMenuDisplay;
```

You are assigning the event with the function not the return value of the function. And make sure you are doing it after declaring the function, else it might throw an undefined error.

```
function SubMenuDisplay()
{
  alert("Hello World!");
  if(!show)
  {
    $('subm').show();
    shown = true;
  }
  else
  {
    $('subm').hide();
    shown = false;
  }
}
document.getElementById("test").onclick = SubMenuDisplay;
```

Comment: I tried as you said but it still doesn't work (even with a copy paste -.- )

Answer (score 0):

Since you decided to use jQuery, then use it (I mean, go to jquery.com and read [the doc](http://api.jquery.com/)):

```js
$('#test > a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

```css
.subm {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="test">
  <a href="#">Account</a>
  <ul class="subm">
    <li><a href="./account.php#login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="./account.php#signup">Sign up</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```